# Find out what flags we are building with in Setup.hs

Tags: haskell, cabal

I need to find out what flags (the type found in cabal files) are being built with in Setup.hs. I think I'm looking for something with type FlagAssignment. How can I get this?

Comment: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.2/html/Cabal/builders.html#flag-control

Comment: @shk that allows me to control flag assignments, I want to find out what flag assignments cabal (or the user has chosen.

Answer (score 1):

Idris has to do this, [you can see the code here](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/blob/d2296e991cd0b604c34a072cf4fa3dd9952f4dce/Setup.hs#L51-L77). In short, read the [`configConfigurationsFlags`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Cabal-1.22.5.0/docs/Distribution-Simple-Setup.html#v:configConfigurationsFlags) of `ConfigFlags` which you can get from the [`configFlags`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Cabal-1.22.5.0/docs/Distribution-Simple-LocalBuildInfo.html#v:configFlags) field of the `LocalBuildInfo` record. `LocalBuildInfo` is passed to every hook when you use [`defaultMainWithHooks`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Cabal-1.22.5.0/docs/Distribution-Simple.html#v:defaultMainWithHooks).

N.B. This information is just the flags passed to configure, so any of them that aren't specified won't be there, rather than having their default values. I think this is a bug, but as of Jan 2016 it's not fixed.

**UPDATE October 2016**: In Cabal-1.24 there is a `flagAssignment` field in `LocalBuildInfo` that has the flags after they're resolved by configuration.